# Is there a way to convert a high precision value to its digits?

Tags: conversion, arbitrary-precision

Is there a way to convert a number like 2.5326384172870370602159219766864657866396178797`20.124930050805514*^-12 to a high precision integer?

Mathematica gives me only 20 digits with `RealDigits[]` when I do this but there are clearly more digits available.

Edit: I should have also stated that I need to do the conversion in Mathematica, not manually.

Comment: For clarity, can you actually put Mathematica code in the body of your question? As it stands, I think I'm misunderstanding your question, because I can't evaluate that numeric expression as is.

Comment: It might also help to explain how you got that number. It looks like it's specifying a precision of 20 digits, and so I'm not sure why you expect any certainty in digits beyond 20.

Comment: So, "integer" was just a mistake, right? That number obviously can't be an integer.

Comment: Maybe what you want is `SetPrecision`, but given that your original number has a precision of about 20 digits, the digits beyond that after you use `SetPrecision` won't be reliable.

Comment: Can you maybe just include what result you actually want to see?

Comment: Maybe if you explain where these numbers are coming from, people might be able to give more appropriate proposals?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the precision of your numbe:r

```
num=2.5326384172870370602159219766864657866396178797`20.124930050805514*^-\
12;
Precision[num]

20.1249
```

By specifying "`20.124930050805514" you decrease the precision explicitly. Delete this:

```
num = 2.5326384172870370602159219766864657866396178797*^-12;
Precision[num]

46.4036
```

And RealDigits will not deliver what you want:

```
RealDigits[num]

{2, 5, 3, 2, 6, 3, 8, 4, 1, 7, 2, 8, 7, 0, 3, 7, 0, 6, 0, 2, 1, 5, 9, 
  2, 1, 9, 7, 6, 6, 8, 6, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 6, 6, 3, 9, 6, 1, 7, 8, 7, 9,
   7}, -11}
```

Comment: That's understood but is there anyway to delete it  with a Mathematica command. I get the sense that one Mathematica sets the precision there's no way to change it.

Comment: To delete the precision specification  is best done with string manipulation . "SetPrecision" will change the precision. However, if you increase the precision, there will be some garbage in the unspecified digits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Windows use Shift+Windows+S and copy your headline to clipboard. Paste it in Mathematica

bild=[image: headline]

Now you can recognize the number string

```
   TextRecognize[bild, Language -> "English"]

    Is there a way to convert a number like 
       2.53263841728703706021592197668646578663961 78797 20.124930050805514*4-\ 12 
    to an high precision integer?
```

Given that the string is interpreted as intended

```
     Rationalize[(2.5326384172870370602159219766864657866396178797`
     20.124930050805514)^- 12, 10^-100]

      1/307390781241935529806
```

or

```
Rationalize[(2.5326384172870370602159219766864657866396178797`20.124930050805514)
    ^- 12, 10^-100]

    7045236/490652289593
```

Comment: Unfortunately,    In[58]:= N[
 Rationalize[(2.5326384172870370602159219766864657866396178797`20.\
124930050805514)^-12, 10^-100]]

Out[58]= 0.0000143589